# React Native Expo - Disable Automatic Update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Everytime I do `expo build:ios`, the app is automatically updated.

I tried disabling the updates from my app.json file but it is still fetching the update automatically.

This is my app.json file

```
    "updates": {
        "enabled": false,
        "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
```

I only want a single version from the app store and playstore. This is really frustrating. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps overriding your app.json with an app.config.js

Also I believe that config needs to be nested on an expo parent field.

"expo": {
"updates": {
"checkAutomatically": "ON_ERROR_RECOVERY"
},